# Thread loop freezes game window

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, audio, timer

I've found a working `Sound` class online and am using it to play sound in a game I'm making. However, I wanted to continuously play the file so I decided just to use a Swing Timer and it works, the only problem is my game window freezes and won't even let you exit it out without using task manager.

Can you please take a look at it and tell me where I went wrong? By the way `main` is just my object variable for my `Sound` class, and `maindelay` is just my `int` for the delay.

```
public static void loopSound(){
    Timer maintime = new Timer(maindelay, new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            main.run();
        }
    });
    maintime.start();
}
```

The `Sound` class I've found:

```
public class Sound extends Thread { 

    private String filename;

    private Position curPosition;

    private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; // 128Kb 

    enum Position { 
        LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
    };

    public Sound(String wavfile) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
    } 

    public Sound(String wavfile, Position p) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = p;
    } 

    public void run() { 

        File soundFile = new File(filename);
        if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
            System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + filename);
            return;
        } 

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try { 
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine auline = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try { 
            auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            auline.open(format);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                    .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
                pan.setValue(1.0f);
            else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
                pan.setValue(-1.0f);
        } 

        auline.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

        try { 
            while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                    auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally { 
            auline.drain();
            auline.close();
        } 

    } 
}
```

Comment: it's an int I initiated it equals 1000

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the sound last longer than 1 second. The int you pass to Timer is in milliseconds. It would seem to me that you are creating the sounds quicker than they can be played and this is clogging your application and blocking the UI (hence the "freeze").

I think using a Timer is the wrong way to repeatedly play the sound. You need instead to modify the sound file.

```
// as Sound
class RepeatSound {
    ...
    public void run() {
        // modify this condition to something meaningful
        while (true) {
            // as original Sound.run() in here
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And call `RepeatSound.start()`. You **must** change that `while(true)` to exit with your application e.g. make it `while (myFrame.visible())` to stop playing once the window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints to solve the problem:

- [Swing Timer API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) states that a timer will repeat the notification to its listeners by default. It means you have an endless loop caused by this timer. See [isRepeats()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#isRepeats%28%29) javadoc.
- Consequently in each iteration a new thread playing a song is created which is not correct at all.
- However as you don't have any interaction between swing components and played song you don't need a Swing timer actually. Just run your `Song` class in a separate thread than the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) and it should be all right.

> However, I wanted to continuously play the file...

As far as I can see in [SourceDataLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html) interface API it extends from [Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html) interface which allows you add [LineListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html)s to listen [LineEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineEvent.html)s. Having said all this you may add a listener to restart the data line when it stops. I'd say it should look like something like this:

```
public class Sound extends Thread { 

    ...

    public void run() 
       ...
       auline.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
           @Override
           public void update(LineEvent e) {
               if(e.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP && e.getLine().isOpen()) {
                   e.getLine().start();
               }
           }
       });
       auline.start();
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Note:** I really don't have time enough to play with this API so it's up to you test if it works. However I made an MP3 player for my cellphone using [Java Mobile Media API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Mobile_Media_API) and the approach was quite similar when I wanted to repeat the same song over again when it finishes.